# How can I properly use bind() on a subImage?

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm having a lot of trouble using the Slick2D `bind()` functionality and then trying to draw an image in OpenGL.

I'm using an `Image` I obtained from `getSubImage`. If I use the `graphics.drawImage()` method it draws this Image perfectly. If, however, I use `bind()`, it binds the entire `Image` that I obtained this sub-image from, so can I not bind sub images or am I doing it wrong?

Some extracts from my code:

In the constructor of my class:

```
ui = new Image("resources/img/ui/ui.png");
// I've tried with SpriteSheet too but Image is more appropriate for my purposes.
border_t = ui.getSubImage(12, 24, 12, 12);
```

In the render method:

```
border_t.bind();
graphics.setColor(Color.white);
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
GL11.glVertex2f(12, 0);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(9, 0);
GL11.glVertex2f(108, 0);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(9, 1);
GL11.glVertex2f(108, 12);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
GL11.glVertex2f(12, 12);
GL11.glEnd();
```

This renders the entire spritesheet 9 times extremely scaled down instead of the top border as I had hoped.

Is this functionality lacking from Slick2d? Is it a bug? Or am I just simply doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Subimages" are a construct of Slick2D, and *only* Slick2D. Once you start talking directly to OpenGL, you're now using *OpenGL* concepts, not Slick2D concepts.

There, there are no "subimages"; there are only textures. You can't bind a part of a texture. You must bind the whole thing. If you want to render a subset of a texture, you need to adjust your texture coordinates accordingly to select just that piece.

So using `bind` on a subimage isn't very useful.

Comment: Oh, I thought that Slick would form a new set of data based on it. Is there any straightforward way of doing this or would I just have to adjust my texCoords?